# How can I solve this? (operator cannot be applied != 'String' to 'Int')

Tags: android, kotlin

```kotlin
activity?.let {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(it.applicationContext,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),1)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your closing parenthesis is in the wrong place, should be

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(it.applicationContext,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```